# Represent Budget remaining percentage when Budget is zero

Tags: arithmetic

I am creating a budget dashboard where the budget is broken down by capitalized costs and expense costs. Where the budget = 0, but expenses are incurred, how do I calculate and represent the budget remaining %? Using the formula in excel gives a Div error.

For instance, if budget for a category = 0, incurred expense is $5,000$, is it logical to say that budget remaining is -$5,000$ and $-5,000$ % ?

Is this a correct representation? What formula can one use to derive the $-5,000$ % ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excel is right: division by $0$ is undefined.

Comment: Percent of what?   As you have remarked, it doesn't really make sense to speak of a percent of $0$.

Comment: See similar post [how-to-treat-a-percentage-division-by-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041526/how-to-treat-a-percentage-division-by-zero).

Comment: Also note that the $-5000\%$ do not provide a meaningful representation of the remaining budget.

Comment: This is more a user interface question than a mathematics question. There is no such percentage. Ask yourself what would be the most informative thing for your user to see on the dashboard. The amount beyond budget rather than the % left? A big red flag?

Comment: Thank you, everyone for the helpful responses. i will update here if find any other helpful ideas.